# How to separate variables?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving

If we had an equation of the form

$f(r)+g(\theta)+\theta^2+c+2r+k(\theta)+10=0$

Is there a way to move the terms containing $r$ to one side and the terms containing $\theta$ to other side like this

$f(r)+c+2r+10=-g(\theta)-\theta^2-k(\theta)$

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

One possible way (used $x$ for $\theta$ as easier to type)

```
ClearAll[f, r, g, x, c, k];
eq = f[r] + g[x] + x^2 + c + 2 r + k[x] + 10 == 0
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
eq = eq /. (stuff_) == 0 :> stuff;
eq = List @@ eq;
lhs = Pick[eq, Not@FreeQ[#, r] & /@ eq];
rhs = Complement[eq, lhs];
eq = Plus @@ lhs == -(Plus @@ rhs)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]